# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sparknlp'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Trying to run Pyspark job on Google Cloud Dataproc.
Even after the installation of `sparknlp` I'm getting this error.
I'm trying to import like this:

```
from sparknlp.annotator import Lemmatizer, Stemmer, Tokenizer, Normalizer
```

And getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sparknlp'
```

Can you help me in finding the reason behind this?

Comment: Which version of Dataproc are you using, how did you install the package? Also check this doc https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration